# create a 3D matrix from 4 columns of a Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matrix, 3d

I want to create a 3D matrix from 4 columns of my dataframe

Input:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
  "u_id": [55218,55218,55218,55222],
  "i_id": [0,0,1,1],
  "Num": [0,2,1,2]
  "rating":[-1,2,0,2]})
```

x-axis : 'u_id';
y-axis : 'i_id'
z-axis : 'Num'

And the value in the Matrix should be 'rating'

The result should be

```
[[[NaN,NaN],
  [-1 ,NaN]],
 [[NaN,NaN],
  [  0,NaN]],
 [[  2,NaN],
  [NaN,2]]]
```

What i tried so far:

```
x = df['u_id']
y = df['i_id']
z = df['Num']
value = df['rating']
Matrix = [[0 for m in len(z)] for m in len(z)] for c in len(x):

Matrix[c][r][m]= value
```

but this doesn't work.

Comment: Your code for the list comprehension is not valid python, for example: `range(df['u_id'])` is not how you use `range`, you are missing a closing bracket, outside the comprehension `c` is not defined. What is your expected output?

Comment: This would result in a 3D array with dimensions `(55223, 2, 3)` to store four values. And would contain exactly the same information as your dataframe.

Comment: ok so, I edited my question. I want a 3D array with the dimensions (2,2,3)

Comment: Your expected output has shape (3,2,2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your expected output doesn't represent the information in your dataframe. But if you want the values of `rating` placed with the other columns as indices in a 3D array with shape `(3,2,2)`

Setup the input data

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
  "u_id": [55218,55218,55218,55222],
  "i_id": [0,0,1,1],
  "Num": [0,2,1,2],      # <-- here was a small typo in your code
  "rating":[-1,2,0,2]})
df
```

Out:

```
    u_id  i_id  Num  rating
0  55218     0    0      -1
1  55218     0    2       2
2  55218     1    1       0
3  55222     1    2       2
```

First convert `u_id` to suitable indices

```
df['u_id'] = df['u_id'].astype('category').cat.codes
df[['Num','u_id','i_id','rating']] # order columns to correspond to coordinates
```

Out:

```
   Num  u_id  i_id  rating
0    0     0     0      -1
1    2     0     0       2
2    1     0     1       0
3    2     1     1       2
```

Then create the output array and fill in the `rating` values

```
x = np.full(df[['Num','u_id','i_id']].nunique(), np.nan)
x[df['Num'], df['u_id'], df['i_id']] = df['rating']
x
```

Out:

```
array([[[-1., nan],
        [nan, nan]],

       [[nan,  0.],
        [nan, nan]],

       [[ 2., nan],
        [nan,  2.]]])
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
What should I change, if i want 0 instead of nan in my array?

Comment: Change the `np.nan` in `np.full(...)` to `0`. This argument is the `fill_value` for the output array.

Comment: If you need both you can use `np.nan_to_num(x, 0)`.